# Linear regression with Lasso penalty needs to increase iterations, Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using Linear regression with Lasso implemented in Scikit-learn package.

```
linear_regress = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = 2)
linear_regress.fit(X, Y)
```

For X, there is 7827 examples and 758 features.
However I got a warning:

```
Objective did not converge for target 0, you might want to increase the number of iterations ' to increase the number of iterations')
```

Meanwhile, the MAE of the cross validation is 0.00304247702091

Then, I followed its advise to increase the number of iterations. (I assume that I am doing correctly):

```
linear_regress = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = 2, max_iter = 100000, tol = 1e-20)
```

But the warning is still there and the MAE increases to 0.0191056040626, which is even worse.

So does anyone know how to fix this problem?

By the way, For the result of cross validation, the MAE of training data is much smaller than that of test data, for instance (alpha=2):

```
The MAE on the TRAINING data is 6.3462754706e-14
The MAE on the TEST data is 0.238521024414
```

I assumed that overfitting exists. But increasing alpha does not help much, for instance(alpha=5)

```
The MAE on the TRAINING data is 1.29613883816e-13
The MAE on the TEST data is 0.0677816327262
```

Increasing alpha also makes the average MAE increases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I guess the warning on `'not converge'` may be due to underfitting, yet you need to verify (probably don't need to set the `tol` value too small). I would suggest you iterate `alpha` through `2^(-5)` to `2^3` in the fitting, and draw a learning curve to observe the  performance on both training and testing data (cross-validation), and select the optimal regularization parameter to best avoid under- and over-fitting.